# How to pull this OFFERID value from a 3rd party JavaScript code and use it in a different 3rd party function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, postback

newbie to coding here, please be gentle... :)

I am trying to pass values from a WooCommerce order and fire it in a HasOffers conversion pixel. How do I pull the OFFERID value from the provided Tracking Code so I can use it in the provided Conversion Code?

Here's the script provided by HasOffers for use with WooCommerce:

**Conversion Code**

```js
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking' );

function my_custom_tracking( $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $total = $order->get_subtotal();
  $order_num = str_replace('#', '', $order->get_order_number());
  echo '<iframe src="https://NETWORKID.go2cloud.org/aff_l?offer_id=OFFERID&amount='.$total.'&adv_sub='.$order_num.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="1" height="1"></iframe>';
}
```

As I understand (which could be wrong), the OFFERID is supposed to be pulled and stored by the following JavaScript snippet (also provided by HasOffers) by adding the tdl.identify() function (https://developers.tune.com/javascript-sdk/getting-started-with-the-javascript-sdk/)

**Tracking Code**

```js
<script>
! function() {
var o = window.tdl = window.tdl || [];
if (o.invoked) window.console && console.error && console.error("Tune snippet has been included more than once.");
else {
    o.invoked = !0, o.methods = ["init", "identify", "convert"], o.factory = function(n) {
        return function() {
            var e = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return e.unshift(n), o.push(e), o
        }
    };
    for (var e = 0; e < o.methods.length; e++) {
        var n = o.methods[e];
        o[n] = o.factory(n)
    }
    o.init = function(e) {
        var n = document.createElement("script");
        n.type = "text/javascript", n.async = !0, n.src = "https://js.go2sdk.com/v2/tune.js";
        var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(n, t), o.domain = e
    }
}
}();

tdl.init("YOUR TRACKING SERVER DOMAIN")

</script>
```

I've spent ~20 hours at this exact issue and haven't really made any real progress. Hoping to get some leads here...thanks

Comment: Can be the tracking code be re-formated and pretiefied? Huge one line of JS is good for machines, but not for humans trying to troubleshoot the code https://beautifier.io/

Comment: @AntonKrug, yeah I agree. That's just exactly how the snippet was provided by HasOffers. At some point it references another JS src = https://js.go2sdk.com/v2/tune.js that contains the OFFERID (offer_id) and other important variables I need such as transaction_id. But I can't figure out how to pass those values to the first WooCommerce code. Thanks!

Comment: You can use tools (like the one I linked above) to make it more readable for people trying to help you, this the result of pretifying the code, now instead 'at some point' you will exactly where it references the tune.js https://jsfiddle.net/73m5wre8/

Comment: Thanks @AntonKrug! I've updated the snippet in the question post with your help / suggestion. I still have trouble figuring out how to extract the offer_id / transaction_id / etc from tune.js to use in the WooCommerce function. I'm not a programmer or developer, just learning JavaScript on the side. Thanks in advance for any pointers you could offer.